# CDPATH configured but not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I've been trying to configure the CDPATH variable to include some directories with long absolute paths, placed on an external drive, but despite telling me the directory is included, the 'cd' command doesn't change directory either way
I used the following commands:

`$ export CDPATH=/media/user/01/workspace/rubystudies`
then
`$ echo $CDPATH`, which returned to me the following:

`/media/user/01/workspace/rubystudies`
However, when I try `cd rubystudies` or `cd /rubystudies` it says
`bash: cd: /rubystudies: No such file or directory`

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is this really how I use `cd` after configuring CDPATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the documentation for the `CDPATH` setting:

> The search path for the cd command.  This is a colon-separated
>   list of directories in which the shell looks for destination
>   directories specified by the cd command.  A sample value is ".:~:/usr".

So, the `CDPATH` setting isn't simply a colon separated list of bookmarks.  It is more similar to the `PATH` setting in that it looks *inside of* each of the listed directories for the directory passed to the `cd` command.

If you want to properly use the setting here, I would try:

```
export CDPATH='.:/media/user/01/workspace'
```

... which would allow you to execute `cd rubystudies/` as you need.

I use the `CDPATH` to hold `.` (the current working directory) and a directory with all of my projects so that I can switch to any one of them from anywhere. You may also want to include your home directory for quick access to the sub-directories it contains.

Comment: May I use this opportunity to ask how to remove a directory from `CDPATH`? I did not add it permanently, but I won't have the option to restart the session if I mistype a permanent directory

Comment: The only way to remove a directory that I know of is to just assign a new value to the `CDPATH` without the directory in question. You should place the desired setting in your `~/.bashrc` to avoid having to define it manually.